# C# Twilio Whatsapp Inbound Message return a MediaUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a message with a quick reply button that I want to send to my users. The quick reply button just says accept. Once the user clicks on it, my server then is supposed to return a link to a file to them.

This works well so far. However, I noticed that the url is sent purely as a text url and not parsed as a file. Is there a way to let the Api know that I want it to be parsed as a File instead of text?

The url is structured like this: https://location.website.com/filename.pdf

This is my code for the Inbound Message Function:

```
[HttpPost("InboundMessage")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public TwiMLResult InboundMessage([FromForm] WhatsappInboundMessage Input)
{
    var em = whatsappMessageLogData.GetAll(Input.From, TenantId);
    if (em.Count > 0)
    {
        em = em.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).ToList();
        var latestItem = em.FirstOrDefault();
        var difference = (DateTime.Now - latestItem.CreatedOn).TotalHours;
        if (difference < 2)
        {
            var message = new Message();
            message.Body($"You can also access the file here: {latestItem.FileAccessLink}");
            message.Media(link);
            response.Append(message);
            return TwiML(response);
        }

    }
    var res = whatsappIMData.Save(Input);
    response.Message(res);
    return TwiML(response);
}
```

This is the twiml response. I only get the url.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Message>
    <Body>You can also access the file here: https://localhost:44332/FileReads/Read?Key=bD4PgsE0Vqq4yMnA5S43WTourBmh3I</Body>
    <Media>https://www.filelink.pdf</Media>
  </Message>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To return files as a media attachment you should nest a `<Media>` element within the `<Message>`:

```cs
        if (difference < 2)
        {
            var message = new Message();
            message.Media(latestItem.Link);
            message.Body("Here's the latest items's link");
            response.Append(message);
            return TwiML(response);
        }
```

See [the documentation for `<Message>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml/message#nouns) for more details and examples.

Comment: Is it possible to return both text and a media url? I followed the c# example in your link but only the media message is shown. The text isnt sent. I tried debugging it and I saw that the message was attached but I only received the media url.

Comment: Yeah, you can use `message.Body("This is the message")` to set the text for a message. I'll update my answer too. [This example in the docs shows how](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml/message?code-sample=code-sending-of-an-message-with-media-mms&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x).

Comment: Yeah I tried that but the only message that appears is the URL.

Comment: I have edited my code in the question to show how I currently do it.

Comment: Check my answer again. You need to create a `Message` object and attach the `Body` and `Media` to the `Message` and then append the `Message` to the `response`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I copied the wrong code. I updated my code to show the correct version.

Comment: Ok, and when you run that code, what is the TwiML that is output?

Comment: Hi @philnash, i added the response in the question

Comment: Are you setting the content type correctly on the response? It should be `text/xml` or `application/xml`.

Comment: How do I do that? I haven't set anything except what you see in th question.

Comment: I checked the code samples on Twilio as well. My response is similar to what is shown on the sample.

Comment: I’m not a C# developer, but I think the TwiMLResult is supposed to handle the content type. But I’m not sure where you’re getting that from. I would check the response yourself or in the Twilio logs to ensure that it is the correct content type and then worry about how to set it if it is wrong.

Comment: The logs do not show any errors. The strange part is that the xml shows the mediaurl and the body but I receive the mediaurl only.